# RecyclerView внутри другого RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, adapter

Хочу добавить в свою приложуху расписание пар. В нашем ВУЗе максимум 5 пар в день, но не факт что таких пар 5 и не факт что в этот день есть пары. Данные сохраняются в БД.  главный `Item` у меня по идее должен быть С `TextView` "День" и `RecyclerView` который является собой тремя `TextView` "№ пары" "числитель" "знаменатель". Я бы сделал это всё как один `item`, но если у меня в день 2 пары, например, то оставшееся место будет попросту пустовать и получаться большие пустые пространства между днями.

На словах всё просто но как этот `RecyclerView` запихнуть в главный `Item` и потом его заполнять? Понимаю, что это небольшое извращение, но другого способа не придумал. [image: Я конечно не художник, но я пытался]

Comment: Попробуйте эту > https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view/blob/master/README.md < либу

Comment: @Flippy 404 page not found

Comment: Sorry, bug is fixed ;)

Comment: @Flippy спасибо) Почитаю)

Comment: Кстати, не забывайте про `ExpandableListView`.

Comment: Ох, видимо это не то, перечитал вопрос. Вам нужен только самый верхний элемент, содержащий подсписок?

Comment: @Flippy подправил описание. Вот примерно на фото. Получается что да) Главный item хранит в себе Какой-то ТекстВью и другой ресайклер, который заполняется в зависимости от наличия данных в БД

Comment: А открываться он должен **именно отталкивая** нижние элементы?

Comment: @Flippy он должен показываться уже раскрытым. И дни идут друг за другом, да

Comment: Стало еще больше непонятно XD. Смотри, тоесть вот этот вот Day и `RecyclerView` должны быть в `RecyclerView`? Или как? И о каком таком пространстве говорится  ) Черт, я уже понял, что ничего не понял

Comment: Выходит, сначала дни, потом пары? А почему бы не сделать это все одним списком? Если их будет два, то нельзя будет ничего скроллить, если что-то не влезет на экран.. Так что все же продумайте логику одного адаптера (itemViewType в помощь). Вложенная прокрутка в списках это бред, вам это надоест после первых же запросов в гугле

Comment: Хмм.. Может я не правильное решение придумал)
Просто если сделать разметку для 5 пар (это максимум), то если в день 2 пары например, пространство для оставшихся 3х просто будет пустым и оно будет создавать пустое пространство. Или я просто тупой и это делается как то просто?

Comment: Ахаха, не тупой, а начинающий :) Список всегда показывает столько, сколько ему дают, не больше, не меньше, на то они и списки :) Тем самым, вам необходимо получить данные о парах и отправить его адаптеру, а тот уже сам позабодится о показе данных. Другое дело, если бы вы у вас были, скажем, 5 контейнеров и вы бы их заполняли руками (у меня так друг игру писал, поле 9*9 он реализовал создав 81 `View`. На этапе присваивания id нервы сдали, а забросил он это дело когда начал писать `findViewById` .....)

Comment: @Flippy Спасибо) Пойду пытаться что сделать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Я бы сделал это всё как один item, но если у меня в день 2 пары, например, то оставшееся место будет попросту пустовать и получаться большие пустые пространства между днями."** - Вот лучше сделайте одним айтемом, в котором 5 пар, чем плодить `RecyclerView` и их адаптеры. "Пары" поместите в `LinearLayout`, те пары которые не пригодятся(если к примеру в этот день только 3 пары) прячьте методом `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)` - тогда у Вас не будет пустого пространства.
При таком подходе для RecyclerView оставить параметр `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false)`.